# how to append html in jQuery Form Plugin without rewriting previous html

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

Hi I am using this code form Jquery Form plugin

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
        target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 

        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
        // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
        success: function() { 
            $('#htmlExampleTarget').fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Here is link to the page http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html
This code overwrites previous code by new one, but what I need is just append new code to the previous html. I have tried simple jquery .append(), but that overwrites the code too.

Comment: i guess you are confusing the word code with the word string or text .. do you actually mean code ?!

Comment: Maybe, the response from the server is like  echo '
 <div id="order_'. $data[0]['id_slide'] . '" class="item"></div>
   <div id="order_'.................

Answer (score 3):

You can get the response and append it your self instead of using target,

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 

        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
        // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
        success: function(response) { 
            $('#htmlExampleTarget').append(response);
            $('#htmlExampleTarget').fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

checkout the success callback [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)

Comment: This works for me as well.  It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the original html content into the dom data storage.
See: [http://api.jquery.com/data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Saves the previous content of #htmlExampleTarget
    var _htmlTarget = $('#htmlExampleTarget');
    _htmlTarget.data('prevHtml', _htmlTarget.html());

    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
        target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 

        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
        // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
        success: function() {
            // prepends the original html content
            var _prevHtml = _htmlTarget.data('prevHtml');
            _htmlTarget.prepend(_prevHtml).fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```